# Create printers from an imported csv file to multiple print servers

Tags: powershell, printing

I have been working with this script and have successfully grabbed info from a .csv file and added it to one print server.

Right now I have the print server hard coded in the script and it allows me to add multiple print servers into the script, but I would like to add the print servers to a column in my .csv file and read from there to eliminate the static servers in the code. Here is what I have:

The second part I am struggling with is publishing and not publishing printers ( listing in AD or not ) I was thinking of adding another column called published. Then creating an if/then to publish or not publish**

```
foreach ($server in @("printserver1")) {
    foreach ($printer in @(Import-Csv C:\PrinterList.csv)) {
        Add-PrinterPort -ComputerName $server -Name $printer.IPAddress -PrinterHostAddress $printer.IPAddress

        Add-Printer -ComputerName $server -Name $printer.Printername -DriverName $printer.Driver -PortName $printer.IPAddress -Comment $printer.Comment -Location $printer.Location -Shared -ShareName $printer.Printername -Published
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `PrinterList.csv` contains a column called `Publish` with `False` or `True` as possible values, you can do the following:

```
foreach ($printer in (Import-Csv C:\PrinterList.csv)) {
    $Params = @{ ComputerName = $server
                 Name = $printer.Printername
                 DriverName = $printer.Driver
                 PortName = $printer.IPAddress
                 Comment = $printer.Comment
                 Location = $printer.Location
                 ShareName = $printer.Printername
    }
    Add-Printer @Params -Shared -Published:([bool]::Parse($printer.Publish))
}
```

Since `Publish` is a `[switch]` parameter, you can use the syntax `-Publish:$true` or `-Publish:$false`. The `Parse()` method parses a string value into a boolean value.

`$Params` [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7) is not necessary here. It just provides a bit more readability.

Alternatively, `[System.Convert]::ToBoolean($printer.Publish)` has the same result in the proposed scenario but does offer more flexibility as `[System.Convert]::ToBoolean(0)` returns `False` and `[System.Convert]::ToBoolean(1)` returns `True`.

Comment: I have a column called Publish but getting this error: Exception calling "Parse" with "1" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid Boolean."
At line:10 char:5
+     Add-Printer @Params -Shared -Published:([bool]::Parse($printer.Pu ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException

Comment: Can you tell me what values you have in that Publish column? It needs to be `True` or `False` to work as it is now.

Comment: I have it as the last column in my csv file. The column is called Publish and right now I have true in there.. all lowercase if that matters at all.

Comment: I am also using the original script you supplied me ( thank you! ) I wasnt sure if I needed to add anything additional. I know you mentioned the -publish: $true and $false

Comment: It should work with any case. Can you tell me which PowerShell version you are using?

Comment: Version is : 5.1.16299.1146